# Transpose data in postgres table

Tags: postgresql

I need to transpose data as shown in the tables below. I will need this to be done dynamically on any number of columns (they can have from 1 up to 100), and i also only want to transpose some of the data. Note that there can be up to millions of rows.

we have new data like this (read from a csv into temp table):

```
id      | name      | field1    | field2    | field3
1       | igig      | a         | b         | cde
2       | ihiuh     | gf        | hi        | pl
3       | pio       | zsfs      | oij       | ugu
4       | xrxf      | iuhi      | vxz       | pkm
5       | rwtre     | xrsd      | as        | jhb
```

we need to do query magic to transpose results like this:

```
id      | column_name   | value
1       | name          | igig
1       | field1        | a
1       | field2        | b
1       | field3        | cde
2       | name          | ihiuh
2       | field1        | gf
2       | field2        | hi
...
```

we want to join this new result set with another table.

Comment: So you are only asking for the transposing step? In other cases we would need a better sample and expected output. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We went with:

```
SELECT id,
       unnest(ARRAY['name','field1','field2']) AS field_name,
       unnest(ARRAY["name", "field1", "field2"]) AS new_value
       FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

The transposing can be done using a JSON operation:

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=22d86a1e04c15788e94c1ec55ad78420)

```
SELECT 
    id,
    elements ->> 'column_name' AS column_name,
    elements ->> 'value' AS value
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        json_build_object('column_name', 'name', 'value', name) AS name,
        json_build_object('column_name', 'field1', 'value', field1) AS field1,
        json_build_object('column_name', 'field2', 'value', field2) AS field2,
        json_build_object('column_name', 'field3', 'value', field3) AS field3
    FROM
        mytable
)s,
unnest(ARRAY[name, field1, field2, field3]) AS elements
```

1. Putting the values and column names into one JSON object
2. Aggregate these columns into one array
3. These array elements can be unnested which results in on row per array element, but all in the same column
4. This column contains all generated JSON objects. So, finally, you are able to parse the original column names and values from this JSON column and give them out in two separate columns.

Magic!

Comment: we did something similar but using unnest instead. i'll post an answer. this probably works, but ours was simpler.